# Who wrote about Hermes Mercury?

Tags: ancient-rome

Which Latin writer wrote about the assimilation of Greek gods? I need more concretely for Hermes-Mercury. Which Latin writer said (assumed) that Hermes was identified with Mercury? I can find this identification in dictionaries on the web or in books, but I need a Latin quotation.

Comment: Ahem... Mercurius @PieterGeerkens :-p

Comment: @SJuan76: Igpay atinlay erhapsay?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need a quote with these particular constraints, but a trivial search of wikipedia references **Interpretatio romana**, which is the core of what you want.  Assimilation of foreign religions through mapping their gods to Roman gods wasn't something any individual did, it was a social practice. Asking who mapped Mercury to Hermes is like asking who decided that Football would be the US National Sport, or that the Beatles were breakout musicians; these aren't determinations made in advance, they are ex post facto observations. The first person to make the observation doesn't deserve any credit.

If however, you need to supply a name, then [Interpretatio romana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_graeca#Interpretatio_romana) suggests [Tacitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacitus).